# Can I use an Excel formula to calculate the sum of some continuous rows?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet and it has some data rows looks like:

```
A    B
---  ---
1    2
2    3
3    1
```

I don't know the rows of the data range until I open the sheet. I want to know, if it's possible to write a formula to calculate

```
1X2 + 2X3 + 3X1 + ...(we may have more rows!)
```

and put the result in a new cell. For now I have to use the formula like

```
A1*B1 + A2*B2 + A3*B3
```

If there are more rows in the data range, I have to add more items in my formula, which is not convenience.

Comment: perhaps you mean "contiguous rows". Spreadsheets are discrete -- I have no idea what it means for rows on such an object to be continuous. By the way -- perhaps `sumproduct` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Try `=SUM(A:A*B:B)` and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: @Fadi, Yes it works. Could you explain how it works?

Comment: @user130268, this array formulas , this is the link :  [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) ,Sorry about my english!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the intended use of the `SUMPRODUCT` function. Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A:A,B:B)
```

Comment: Thank you! Why here I can't write it as `=SumProduct("A:A", "B:B")`?

Comment: You're welcome. I guess the answer to your comment is just that that syntax won't work.